# Multiple INSERTS in one query Joomla

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

How can I do multiple inserts like:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `table` (`fied1`, `field2`, `field3`) VALUES ('one', 'two', 'three'),('four', 'five', 'six');
INSERT INTO `table` (`fied1`, `field2`, `field3`) VALUES ('seven', 'eight', 'nine'),('ten', 'eleven', 'twelve');"
$db->setQuery($query);
$db->query();
```

I can't split this query because I'm getting it from large text file.

Comment: use mysql's extended syntax. `insert into table (fields) values (dataset1), (dataset2), (dataset3), etc...`

Comment: I need to comply with the max_allowed_packet limit = 16Mb :(

Comment: easy enough to build up the query string in a loop and send it over once you start getting close to the limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the docblock for the `insert` method

```
/**
 * Add a table name to the INSERT clause of the query.
 *
 * Note that you must not mix insert, update, delete and select method calls when building a query.
 *
 * Usage:
 * $query->insert('#__a')->set('id = 1');
 * $query->insert('#__a')->columns('id, title')->values('1,2')->values('3,4');
 * $query->insert('#__a')->columns('id, title')->values(array('1,2', '3,4'));
 *
 * @param   mixed    $table           The name of the table to insert data into.
 * @param   boolean  $incrementField  The name of the field to auto increment.
 *
 * @return  JDatabaseQuery  Returns this object to allow chaining.
 *
 * @since   11.1
 */
```

so something like

```
$query->insert('table')
->columns(`fied1`, `field2`, `field3`)
->values(array('one, two, three', 'four, five, six'));
```

Online I think you probably have a spelling mistake on the first field name and I might use `$db->quoteName(array('field1', 'field2', field3'))` if there was a chance I could be passing in a variable representing an array of different field names later.